# Perl socket parse packets from a network stream

Tags: perl, sockets, parsing, stream

I am trying to figure out a proper way to parse a stream of data using perl.
I have read through many of the examples, documentations and questions, but could not find how I could basically cut a "package" from the stream of data and process it.
This is the situation:
 - stream of data coming from a certain IP to an IP and port 
 - stream contains some gibberish and then something between  and  with the data in there being semicolon seperated

My attempts so far is to have a Socket listening on the port and process the $data var:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use IO::Socket::INET;
    # auto-flush on socket
    $| = 1;

# creating a listening socket
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
    LocalPort => '7070',
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => 5,
    Reuse => 1
);
die "cannot create socket $!\n" unless $socket;
print "server waiting for client connection on port 7070 \n";

while(1)
{
    # waiting for a new client connection
    my $client_socket = $socket->accept();

    # get information about a newly connected client
    my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
    my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
    print "connection from $client_address:$client_port\n";

    # read up to 1024 characters from the connected client
    my $data = "";
    $client_socket->recv($data, 1024);
    print "received data: $data\n";

    @data_array = split(/;/,$data);
    foreach (@data_array) {
      print "$_\n";
    }

    # write response data to the connected client
    $data = "ok";
    $client_socket->send($data);

    # notify client that response has been sent
    shutdown($client_socket, 1);
}

$socket->close();
```

This works but as far as I understand this will put the whole stream in up to the size and then process that.

My question:
How can I identify the part I need (start-end), process that and then go on to the next?

Comment: An example of incoming data would be useful to understand the problem -- we don't know what defines the part you need. Note that you can usually assume that stream sockets relay data perfectly, so to avoid gibberish appearing at the receiver the best countermeasure would be to avoid sending it. f you don't control the source, your best bet would be to look for framing data and start parsing from there.

Answer (score 5):

I've never understood why people use `recv` to read from a stream socket.

Normally, the reading loop looks something like the following:

```
my $buf = '';
while (1) {
   my $rv = sysread($socket, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf));
   if (!defined($rv)) {
      die("Can't read from socket: $!\n");
   }

   if (!$rv) {
      die("Can't read from socket: Premature EOF\n") if length($buf);
      last;
   }

   while (my $msg = defined(check_for_full_message_and_extract_it_from_buf($buf))) {
      process_msg($msg);
   }
}
```

(Keep in mind that sysread returns as soon as there is some data, even if there's less data than requested.)

For example, the inner loop for sentinel-terminated data would look like the following:

```
   while ($buf =~ s/^(.*)\n//) {
      process_msg("$1");
   }
```

For example, the inner loop for length-prefixed blocks would look like the following:

```
   while (1) {
      last if length($buf) < 4;

      my $len = unpack('N', $buf);
      last if length($buf) < 4+$len;

      substr($buf, 0, 4, '');
      my $msg = substr($buf, 0, $len, '');
      process_msg($msg);
   }
```

If you're particular case, you'd remove any data from the start `$buf` that you want to ignore until you get to the part in which you're interested, then you'd start extracting the items in which you are interested. This is vague, but I only have a vague description of the protocol with which to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid my current perl knowledge is too limit to be able to use it. At the same time I may have made the wrong assumptions about the input, it seems it is a tcp connection containing some data about length.

Since I am really interested in the solution I asked for, let's continue on that. Why do you prefer sysread over recv? If I understand correctly you basically read 64 bytes, check for the data and have a seperate sub take care of buffer manipulation? I was thinking to process per character/byte so I could check one I have a complete "message".

Comment: Re "*Why do you prefer sysread over recv?*", `recv` is for receiving messages, but streams have no such things. At best, `recv` does exactly the same thing as `sysread`. /// Re "*you basically read 64 bytes*", As I already mentioned, it reads _up to_ 64 KiB. (The exact number isn't important, but larger is usually faster.) /// Doesn't have to be a separate sub. Just a descriptive place-holder. ///  Re "*I was thinking to process per character/byte*", Reading a byte at a time would be insanely slow. As for actually how to check for a full message, the solution will vary by protocol.

Comment: The protocol should have been defined in the Question, and that's where it should be placed. If you do, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is an example of the message markup:
`.......I.....].....
....^..<START>>.......................N...ABC123MSG_Default;source=AB123MSG;origin=SEABCD01.SIPO1;sub_origin='';hostname=SEABCD01.SIPO2;adapter_host=IPO2TCP;date='MAY 08 10:10:10';severity=CRITICAL;msg='ING_EVENT: ABCDE_GDPAB123 FGD123B ABC MONITORING FROM IPO1 OK';adapter_host_somenode=BEABCD01.SIPO2;msg_id='ING_EVENT:';multiline_msg=[N/A];jobname='';sub_source=Unknown;END
.
D..4..@.3.d.`

As far as I understand I cannot 'grep' in the stream, so I need to fetch a chunk and see if all is there and otherwise continue?

Comment: You didn't not provide any new information. (And you completely disregarded my comment as to where that should be posted!!!)

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but I am new to this and I don't know where to do that. I love this site for information but for posting I think it is terrible. Anyway, I almost have a solution now. I basically use a variable like in your example for the buffer and understood once read, the data is out of the socket (correct :)?). I will just write some logic that will keep track if the fetched END contains START or a part of it and keep track in a variable and it should be golden. Thanks for the help, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: It's only terrible if you use it to chat. Click "edit" under your Question if you need to fix up or improve your Question.

Comment: well I did add new information, right? And I do not understand your answer to my sysread question. Never knew this site was so counter intuitive in use :). Oh and I try to move to chat but had not enough reputation. I'll think twice before posting anything again ;).
Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, you didn't provide any new information. You just posted the same information in a different way. Still have no idea where the relevant bit starts and where the relevant ends (generally speaking). /// I used `sysread` because it's the only tool that makes sense to use. `recv` is "*used to receive messages from a socket*", which makes no sense for streams.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the original code and adding :

```
if ( $data=~/<START>>/) {
    print "\nFound start\n";
    $message.=$data;
    while ($message !~/END/){
        $client_socket->recv($data, $message_length);
        $message.=$data;
        print "\nStill reading\n"; 
    };
    print "\nFound end\n"; # but may contain (part of) next START
}
```

I still need to implement the part where I check if the chunk read has part of the next message, but I'll figure that out.
Thank you for the help!